# Eclipse error on Startup in every project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is a problem that I have encountered several times, and asked about previously on SO with no responses.  The issue that I'm having is that sometimes when I start up Eclipse to work on my Android projects, I get tons of errors.  What I realized now is that the folders `Android 4.4.2` and `Android Private Libraries` are missing, which is clearly causing the error.  I tried updating my SDK and cleaning the project, neither of which resolved the issue.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the proper way to fix this problem?  I understand that I can just copy the `Android 4.4.2` folder into my project, but that is a very hacky and temporary solution.  I am looking for something that will actually resolve this.
2. How can I prevent this from happening again/why is this happening.  Two possible thoughts I had were that it either happens when Eclipse force-quits, or when there are Android updates that I have to install, but I don't see why either of these would cause a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just In case… Are you using a Mac?
It could actually happen if you "accidentally" manipulate your computer permissions.

I know it's not the easy way but try this:

1. download (again) the android development kit.
2. Find your current sdk, erase it and the empty folder with the sdk from de ask you just downloaded.
3. Open Eclipse, and choose update

This is kinda a force-clean but it works most of the time. 
Otherwise if anything works I recommend using Android Studio. It's still a beta but works quite good for me.